# Remove a script with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have a problem with my jQuery. So, I want to remove a script who is inside a `<div>`.
My html is :

```
<div id="right-bloc">
        <div class="right-bloc-pub-1">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://firstScript.com"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="right-bloc-pub-2">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://secondScript.com"></script>
        </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery :

```
 var stringOfHtml = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://firstScript.com"></script>';
 var html = $(stringOfHtml);
 html.find('script').remove();
```

I want to remove the script witch contains `http://firsttScript.com`, but not working. It's possible to remove this script and add after? Because I need to refresh this script

Comment: Does that `<script>` exist in your actual html? or just a variable?

Comment: Better solution: `$('#right-bloc').find('script[src="http://firstScript.com"]').remove()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify it as the following code:

```
html.find('script[src="http://firstScript.com"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `<script>` tags are actually in your html DOM and you have jQuery reference included.

You can use `.filter()` to get the `script` with `src` as `'http://firstScript.com'` and the `.remove()`.

```
$('html').find('script').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src') === 'http://firstScript.com'
}).remove();
```

---

Also,

```
var stringOfHtml = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://firstScript.com"></script>';
var html = $(stringOfHtml);
```

This is *Not* allowed and would throw error `Unexpected Token Illegal`

Comment: It's possible to add after remove this script? Because I need to refresh the script

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.right-bloc-pub-1').find('script[src="http://firstScript.com"]').remove();
   });
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.right-bloc-pub-1').find('script').attr('src', 'http://firstScript.com').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only need changes

```
    var html = $(stringOfHtml);
    html.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

To select and remove your first script you can do this way : `$('script[src="http://firstScript.com"]').remove()`

Just know that this will remove the script from your DOM but not the library loaded within this script. For example if your first script load jQuery, the `$` variable will still contains jQuery. To remove completely jQuery you can add `$ = undefined; jQuery = undefined;`

Comment: To add again your script (if you want to refresh it) you can do this way : `$('.right-bloc-pub-1').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://firstScript.com"></script>')`

I recommend you to use the id attribute here rather than the class, assuming it will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.right-bloc-pub-1').html().remove();
});
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete events related with that script.
So you must look for events that belong to that script.
The `$._data(document,'events')` is best choice to start with.