# Jquery/Javascript: How to Remove JS file for a page which is not being used in current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getscript

Basically I have 4 views in my page (4 different sections in a single HTML page), I am hiding and showing the required views based on the button click.

I have 4 separate JS file for these 4 views. Based on the page user is in I am loading the JS page using the command

```
    //Page1
    if (current_page == 'Page1') {
        $.getScript("/js/Page1.js");
    }
```

I want to remove the all unused JS (JS which are used for other pages) when user navigates to 2nd page and only `Page2.js` should be loaded, Currently when user navigates to 2nd page (Page1 to Page2) both `Page1.js` and `Page2.js` are being loaded.

`$.getScript` can load the JS but is there a command or way to remove the JS from page and load the JS file dynamically?

Comment: No dear, you can't undo loaded js, all you can do is cleanup your actual code instead, removing unused scripts/plugins.

Comment: @Arvind What do you mean by `clean up your actual code`?  I didn't get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the response, I was able to figure out the issue and some workaround for that.
Basically I had some common functions in Page1 JS and Page2 JS so I wanted some of the functions in my Page2 JS not to run when I am using Page1 but they were getting executed because of them were using same modal and form submit IDs.

I declared a variable in the JS and Based on that I made sure the functions in Page2 JS not running when I am in Page1

```
    var Page_Checker = "";
    //Page1
    if (current_page == 'Page1') {
        $.getScript("/js/Page1.js");
        Page_Checker = "THIS_IS_PAGE1"
    }
```

Use the `Page_Checker` and make sure the functions are not running in other JS files.
May be you can do something like this in other JS files:

```
if(Page_Checker != "THIS_IS_PAGE1")
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072887/remove-a-script-with-jquery) a good post that explains it, but hat you can do is remove the `<script>` element you are not using:

```
<script id="page1script" src="/js/Page1.js"></script>
```

And in jQuery:

```
if (current_page != 'Page1') {
    $("#page1script").html().remove();
}
```

Comment: technically seems it does not make any difference